# In gradle.build file, is there a way to access what the user has passed in as --tests?

Tags: gradle

For example, if the user runs `gradle clean test --tests some.package.SomeTest` is there a way that I could do `System.out.println("User passed " + task.commandToGetWhatUserPassedAsTests())` in the gradle.build file and see in the output `User passed some.package.SomeTest`

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question.

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
  for(TaskExecutionRequest taskExecutionRequest : project.gradle.startParameter.taskRequests) {
    for(Iterator<String> iterator = taskExecutionRequest.args.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
      if(iterator.next().equals("--tests")) {
        System.out.println("--tests" + iterator.next())
      }
    }
  }
}
```